# Move data from Google Cloud bucket to my FireBase bucket

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

I have a google cloud account with one storage bucket.  I just opened a firebase project which has a storage bucket included.  I would like to move the data from my original bucket to my new FireBase bucket.

Comment: Use gsutil to copy files to and from buckets.

Comment: I tried that, but had the syntax wrong - my bad! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Doug!
Use gsutil to copy files to and from buckets. – Doug Stevenson